# How to add a String to nth line of a file

Tags: java, json, file

So I'm trying to add a string into a specific line(for example a line that contains a word) of a JSON file.

my main problem is after i access the file i don't know how to reach that specific line and put the string inside there.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
                String newLine=crp.makeLine();
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                for (int i=0;i<=lineCounter;i++){
                    br.readLine();
                    if(i==lineCounter){
                        out.write(newLine);
                    }
                }
```

I've tried this but it just writes the newLine to the end of the JSON file not the line that i specified through lineCounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening makes sense, because you are indeed inserting the "newLine" at the end of your file, to it the right way, you should get all the content of your file, store it in a StringBuffer then do your modifications, after that you can rewrite the file.
Here is a demonstration code:

```
try {
        // input the file content to the StringBuffer "input"
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            inputBuffer.append(line);
            inputBuffer.append('\n');
        }
        file.close();
        String inputStr = inputBuffer.toString();

        System.out.println(inputStr); // display the original file for debugging

            int wordIndex = inputStr.indexOf('the word')
            inputStr = inputStr.substring(0, wordIndex ) + "new string" + inputStr.substring(wordIndex , inputStr.length());             

        // display the new file for debugging
        System.out.println("----------------------------------\n" + inputStr);

        // write the updated content with the new string OVER the same file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fileOut.write(inputStr.getBytes());
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
```

please check the code for errors as this is only a demonstration code.

Comment: one question:    inputStr = inputStr.substring(0, wordIndex ) + "new string" + inputStr.substring(wordIndex , x.length());                                                                            in this line, what does variable x represent?

Comment: the "x" refers to "inputStr", I have just fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correctly reading to the line you want to write to. However, your writer, which you have opened in append mode will only ever write at the end of the file. There is no correlation between where you have read in the file to where you are writing to in the file.

If you consider a file as an array, you can't just write arbitrarily to any part in the middle (i.e. using random access) without overwriting the existing contents. At the very least you have to copy everything from the point you want to insert to the end, write what you want to insert and then append everything you copied to the end.

---

If you want to avoid reading the entire file into memory you could process the file line by line into a temporary file and then if it is successful copy the temporary file over the original file at the end.

```
    public void insertLine(File f, String newLine, int lineCounter) throws IOException {
        File temp = File.createTempFile(f.getName(), ".temp");
        temp.deleteOnExit();

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp))) {
            try (LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                reader.lines().forEachOrdered(line -> {
                    if (reader.getLineNumber() == lineCounter) {
                        writer.println(newLine);
                    }
                    writer.println(line);
                });
            }
        }

        Files.copy(temp.toPath(), f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        temp.delete();
    }
```

If you need more flexibility or the ability to add, edit or remove multiple lines you could look at passing in a listener/function of sorts.

```
    public interface LineModifierFunction {
        boolean line(String line, int lineNumber, PrintWriter writer);
    }
```

Where the return value determines if the original line should be written as well as the function being allowed to write its own lines.

```
    public void insertLine(File f, LineModifierFunction listener) throws IOException {
        File temp = File.createTempFile(f.getName(), ".temp");
        temp.deleteOnExit();

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp))) {
            try (LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                reader.lines().forEachOrdered(line -> {
                    if (listener.line(line, reader.getLineNumber(), writer)) {
                        writer.println(line);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        Files.copy(temp.toPath(), f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        temp.delete();
    }
```

And this would be called in your example as follows:

```
        insertLine(f, (l, n, p) -> {
            if (n == lineCounter) {
                p.println(crp.makeLine());
            }
            return true;
        });
```

or in old money

```
        insertLine(f, new LineModifierFunction() {
            public boolean line(String l, int n, PrintWriter p) {
                if (n == lineCounter) {
                    p.println(crp.makeLine());
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

---

**Finally I really wouldn't recommend this approach for a JSON payload.** This algorithm makes the assumption that the JSON is formatted with a single field on each line and that no values are multi-line. You would be better off reading with a JSON parser, inserting the new node or modifying an existing value and then writing the object back out as JSON.
Consider looking at Jackson ObjectMapper or GSON.